# AutoIT How do I perform a recursive search?

Tags: recursion, autoit

In AutoIT I'm making a script that needs to be able to recursively search a certain area for all files. I've read up on it online and all of the scripts that I've tried use functions that I'm not able to use. Do any of you guys have a script that I could use to recursively search a directory and save all of the files it finds to an array? If you could do this I'd be incredibly happy, Anyways thanks in advance.

Comment: What functions aren't you able to use? All you need is FileFindFirstFile and FileFindNextFile.

Answer (score 3):

Try _FileListToArrayRec it is a new function from the UDFs. It should be very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

**Notice:**

As a example how to use the `_FileListToArrayRec()` function to save all found files in an array as mentioned. Please have a look in the help file for more details.

**Code:**

```cpp
#include-once
#include <Array.au3>
#include <File.au3>

Global $sPathToSearch  = @AppDataDir
Global $sFileExtension = 'txt' ; or '*' for all files or 'pdf' for just PDFs

Global $aFileList = _FileListToArrayRec( $sPathToSearch, '*.' & $sFileExtension, 1, 1, 0, 2 )
If IsArray( $aFileList ) Then _ArrayDisplay( $aFileList )
```